# why Ajax get Request failed

Tags: ajax, jquery, xmlhttprequest

The response of my request is a java script code. When I put the url in browser, I can see the whole generated java script code on the page. Format of url passed to $.ajax is as below:

```
http://localhost:8080/vi-api/viapi?action=tag&projectId=45&tagId=345
```

When I put the above URL I can see the request is successful. Now, I am using below Ajax request for this url using jQuery.

```
   var finalUrl = "http://localhost:8080/vi-api/viapi?action=tag&projectId=45&tagId=345";
   var req = $.ajax({
             type:"GET",
             url:finalUrl,
             type:"script",
             data:"",
             success: function(html){
                alert('Requese sucessful.');
              },
            complete:function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                alert("request complete "+textStatus);
             },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert('request failed->'+textStatus);
            }             
           });
```

Question 1:This gives the alert "request failed error'. Why this is so ?

Question 2:Is there any way to return success/failure code in above process?

Comment: Syntax error in line 1..

Comment: ok. sorry, I am using string only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In:

```
$.ajax({
     type:"GET",
     url:finalUrl,
     type:"script",
     (...)
```

You have two times the 'type' key in your object. So I think only the second one is taken ('script'). Obviously 'script' is not a valid HTTP method (as HEAD,GET,PUT,POST, etc). The keyword your were looking at for 'script' is maybe `dataType` which may be one of `xml`, `json`, `jsonp`, `text`, `script`, or `html`.

Do not forget to look at `jsonp`, it's usually a nice way to return a script content and to call it.

Comment: +1 cool..! You are brilliant. Now,half problem is solved. but, why success is called here ?

Comment: Umesh: I don't understand your question, `why success is called?` when is it called, why do you think it shouldn't be called?

Comment: sorry. typing mistake. I wanted success to be called. but, it is not done in with this code. It is calling error and complete functions.

Comment: Umesh: now that dataType is fixed (and present only once as well), can you see the request in firebug (and the response), and what are the content of xhr, textStatus, errorThrown (use console.log() ) in your error handler?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why, but I can give your some tips how to debug or find out issues:

1) install [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) to look at HTTP request.

2) type:"script", why the type is script? try to use "text/html".

3) use `complete(jqXHR, textStatus)` you can look at HTTP status. [more info about $.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Thank you. Same type of execution even with "text/html". I added complete() in the code to test. Complete has been called and 'textStatus' is error. Actually, I can't see request being made in Firebug.

Comment: Testing with fiddler saved me in another scenario. I forgot to use JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet in Asp.net MVC response JSON result.

Answer (score 1):

```
var finalUrl=http://localhost:8080/vi-api/viapi?action=tag&projectId=45&tagId=345;
```

is pretty invalid javascript. You probably meant passing the url as a string:

```
var finalUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/vi-api/viapi?action=tag&projectId=45&tagId=345';
```

Comment: @Umesh, so is the AJAX request sent? Do you see it in FireBug? Where does the error occur? On which line?

Comment: Hello Darin, I am not getting any request in Firebug Net tab, but Above code gives 2 alerts- 1.request failed->error 2.request complete error.

This means 'complete' and 'error' are being called with this url.

Comment: Maybe you are violating the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) which prevents you from sending cross domain AJAX requests? Is the page containing this script hosted on `http://localhost:8080/`? Or maybe there's simply an error with the server side endpoint that you are trying to invoke? What HTTP status code do you see in the Network tab? What's the response from the server?

Comment: +1. thank you.this may be the case as code seems to be correct.  page is not on server. I am checking, will let you know within few mins.

Comment: Darin, half problem is solved. I placed page on server. but, I want to see 'success' being called. As my ajax request is done here.